# If $P''(x)\mid P(x)$ then $P(x)$ has all roots real or less than $3$.

Tags: polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with real coefficients, such $P(x)$ has more than $3$ real roots. Assume that $P''(x)\mid P(x)$.

Prove that $P(x)$ has $n$ real roots.

Comment: First off, do you mean $n$ real roots? Also, are the $x_i$ distinct? Next, what have you tried?

Comment: $x_i$ can be $x_j$

Comment: This question needs a lot of clarification.  The $x_i$ aren't used except to note that they are 'roots of $P$', and the '$n$ roots' condition is vague both in the realness of the roots and also their distinctness.

Comment: Do you mean that all $n$ roots are real numbers?

Comment: Thomas Andrews :yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$P(x) = (x-x_1)^{k_1}(x-x_2)^{k_2} \ldots (x-x_j)^{k_j}.$$ We know by the product rule or the logarithmic derivative that

$$\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)} = \sum_{i = 1}^j \frac{k_i}{x-x_i}.$$
Similarly, let $$P'(x) = (x-y_1)^{m_1}(x-y_2)^{m_2} \ldots (x-y_n)^{m_n}.$$

Then
$$\frac{P''(x)}{P'(x)} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{m_i}{x-y_i}.$$
Multiplying gives

$$\frac{P''(x)}{P(x)} = \left( \sum_{i = 1}^j \frac{k_i}{x-x_i} \right) \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{m_i}{x-y_i} \right) = \frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}$$ since $P''(x)|P(x)$.

The functions on the left hand side are rational functions with quadratic or linear denominators and they are all linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Therefore, each product $$\frac{k_rm_s}{(x-x_r)(x-y_s)} = \frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}. $$ Therefore, all the roots of $P(x)$ are just the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$. So we only needed $P(x)$ to have one real root instead of more than $3$.

Comment: but i don't understand why **they are all linearly independent over** $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and why that implies  each product $\frac{k_rm_s}{(x-x_r)(x-y_s)} = \frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}.$

Comment: They are all linearly independent comes from computing the Wronksian. This means that $\sum_i c_if_i(x) = 0$ implies $c_i = 0$. If they were different functions, all of the constant multipliers would be $0$ so we would have $0 = \frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}$ which is false.